# How to trigger an code written in python from java?

Tags: java, python

I have a script written in python and i want to trigger it only after completing an process in JAVA .
How could i trigger it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another and newer way, will be use the `ProcessBuilder` class, this gives more structure to the arguments.
You can read the `ProcessBuilder` documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html).

```
class Test2 {
    public static void main(String a[]) {
        try {

            String prg = "import sys\nprint int(sys.argv[1])+int(sys.argv[2])\n";
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("test1.py"));
            out.write(prg);
            out.close();
            int number1 = 10;
            int number2 = 32;

            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("python", "test1.py", ""
                    + number1, "" + number2);
            Process p = pb.start();

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    p.getInputStream()));
            int ret = new Integer(in.readLine()).intValue();
            System.out.println("value is : " + ret);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

To better understand please refer to [this post.](https://bytes.com/topic/python/insights/949995-three-ways-run-python-programs-java)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly, but provided that you can call the Python executable from the console and just want to capture its output in Java, you can use the exec() method in the Java Runtime class.

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python yourapp.py");
```

You can read up on how to actually read the output here:

http://www.devdaily.com/java/edu/pj/pj010016

There is also an Apache library (the Apache exec project) that can help you with this. You can read more about it here:

http://www.devdaily.com/java/java-exec-processbuilder-process-1

http://commons.apache.org/exec/